# Query Xml in SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

I am new to SQL Server and T-SQL. How can I query out the information stored in this xml in SQL Server 2008 R2?

XML :

```
<smp:Root xmlns:smp="http://tempuri.org/smp.xsd" header="Test Title">
  <smp:Sections>
    <smp:G3 idnumber="01">
      <SectionHost>ABC</SectionHost>
    </smp:G3>
    <smp:G2 idnumber="01">
      <SectionHost>DEF</SectionHost>
    </smp:G2>
  </smp:Sections>
</smp:Root>
```

Comment: I added another link for the Xpath functions, they can help as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have the `Xml` stored in a `Xml` column just use the `value method` to `shred` the `Xml`.

Next time try and post some `DDL, DML` to show us what you have tried, your table structures etc.

But try this

```
WITH XMLNAMESPACES (Default 'http://tempuri.org/smp.xsd')
SELECT     
    a.value('@header', 'nvarchar(50)') as Header,
    b.value('local-name(.)', 'nvarchar(50)') as Sections,
    b.value('@idnumber' ,'int') as IdNumber,
    b.value('.' , 'nvarchar(20)') as Host

From ATable As x   

                Cross Apply x.AXmlColumn.nodes('Root') a(a) 
                               Cross Apply a.nodes('Sections/*') b(b)
```

Here are some useful `links` to get you started:

https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/learn-sql-server/the-xml-methods-in-sql-server/

http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/01/15/sql-server-what-is-dml-ddl-dcl-and-tcl-introduction-and-examples/

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189254.aspx